# C++ Variadic Macro To Specify Multiple Conditions

Tags: c++, c, macros

I suspect that I can't do this, but figured I'd ask the wise community here first.

I want to check if any of a handful (say ten, though probably just two or three) of variables are equal to the same specific value. e.g.

```
if (X == 3 || Y == 3 || Z == 3 || W == 3) ...
```

In Python I'm used to simply doing `if 3 in (X, Y, Z, W):`, but whatever.

Anyway, I'm wondering if it's possible to abstract it into a variadic macro such as `EQU_ANY(3, X, Y, Z, W)` instead of writing a bunch of `EQU_ANYX` macros where X is the number of args.

Comment: No, macros are the wrong tool -- there's no way to iterate over parameters in a macro.

Comment: Thanks Jim, that's what I wanted to know. (Ahh if only I had Lisp macros..)

Comment: Well, it turns out that I was wrong -- the boost::preprocessor package has truly devious ways of achieving this for up to 256 parameters. See the answers by Jonathan and James (you really ought to accept the latter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The solution using a macro is at the end, because it's rather horrible and yucky.]

---

If you don't mind copies being made, it's probably cleaner to use `std::find`:

```
std::array<int, 4> values = { X, Y, Z, W };
if (std::find(values.begin(), values.end(), 3) != values.end()) { }
```

It's often nice to wrap this line into a function:

```
template <typename Container, typename Value>
bool contains(const Container& c, const Value& v) 
{
    return std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), v) != c.end();
}
```

used as:

```
std::array<int, 4> values = { X, Y, Z, W };
if (contains(values, 3)) { }
```

In C++0x, you can use an initializer list instead of creating a temporary array:

```
if (contains({ X, Y, Z, W }, 3)) { }
```

(This works in gcc 4.5+; I'm not aware of any other compilers that support this C++0x feature yet.)

---

If you really want to avoid copying the objects (e.g., if they are large or expensive to copy), you can use an indirect version of the same function:

```
#include <boost/iterator/indirect_iterator.hpp>

template <typename Container, typename Value>
bool indirect_contains(const Container& c, const Value& v)
{
    return std::find(boost::make_indirect_iterator(c.begin()),
                     boost::make_indirect_iterator(c.end()),
                     v) 
        != boost::make_indirect_iterator(c.end());
}
```

Used as:

```
std::array<int*, 4> values = { &X, &Y, &Z, &W };
if (indirect_contains(values, 3)) { }
```

Or, with a C++0x initializer list:

```
if (indirect_contains({ &X, &Y, &Z, &W }, 3)) { }
```

---

Since Jonathan Leffler mentioned Boost.Preprocessor, here is what that solution would look like:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define SEQUENCE_CONTAINS_IMPL(r, data, i, elem)                          \
    BOOST_PP_IIF(BOOST_PP_EQUAL(i, 0), BOOST_PP_EMPTY(), ||)              \
    ((elem) == (data))


#define SEQUENCE_CONTAINS(elements, value)                                \
    (BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(SEQUENCE_CONTAINS_IMPL, value, elements))
```

Used as:

```
if (SEQUENCE_CONTAINS((X)(Y)(Z)(W), 3)) { }
```

Which expands to:

```
if ((((X) == (3)) || 
     ((Y) == (3)) || 
     ((Z) == (3)) || 
     ((W) == (3)))) { }
```

(This is ugly and horrible; I wouldn't use this in my code, but if you're really worried about copies of two or three values being made, you probably don't want to chance a function call being made either.)

Comment: Re: your edit, thanks! I probably won't use it, I agree it's pretty ugly, but still it's awesome Boost can do that.

Comment: @Kevin Regardless of whether copies are evil, the solution James gave using boost::preprocessor satisfies your original request and has nothing to do with copies.

Comment: @Jim Balter Yes, hence I accepted it as the solution. The only arguable problem with using it now is its slight ugliness (it's not that bad), and more importantly bringing in whatever Boost dependencies are required by its preprocessor. The nice thing about the copy-solution is that it's standard (for gcc anyway).

Comment: The Boost.Preprocessor library _shouldn't_ have any dependencies, so you _should_ be able to take the "Preprocessor" source directory and "Preprocessor.hpp" and just use them. (I know, I know, I said _should_ :-D. I'm almost certain, though.) In addition, it works with C code as well, since it's purely a preprocessing library (C90 and C++03 have almost identical preprocessing specifications).  I'm curious as to whether an `initializer_list` can take references though...)

Comment: @Kevin Boost uses the compiler's preprocessor; there are no dependencies. Just download and install it and start `#include`ing -- there's nothing else that needs doing.

Comment: @James: you could remove the `BOOST_PP_IF` call if you expanded the first element through `BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD` and passed only `BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL` to the iteration.

Comment: @James, I find both solutions ugly and horrible. I'll give another  answer that uses variadic macros (and thus only works reliably with C99) below.

Comment: @Jens:  I think the Boost.Preprocessor sequences aren't so horrible once you get used to them.  That said, you're right:  the solution using variadic macros is better; I've not programmed much in C at all, so I have very little familiarity with what can be done with variadic macros:  that's pretty cool.

Comment: @Matthieu:  Ah, that's good to know.  I'll have to look at that.  If they had named them `BOOST_PP_SEQ_CAR` and `_CDR`, maybe I'd have noticed them before ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a switch statement. You can specify the same behavior for multiple conditions like so:

```
switch (n) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        // Do something
        break;
}
```

That's the equivalent of

```
if (x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3)
    // Do something
```

That's the cleanest way to do this. You might be able to write a variadic switch macro (or something that accomplishes something like that), but please, for everyone around you... don't :P

Comment: This works, until I want to use something besides ints or chars. I still want a Macro though since using switch leads to _more_ typing (than even the conditional!), not less, and I'd bet the compiler is smart enough to optimize those trivial conditions to switches/gotos. **Edit** Wait, your way makes me more confused...

Comment: @Kevin the conditional is okay for a few conditions, but when you get 5 or more, it's much better to write the switch. Testing equality with `==` does not work for strings or floats, IIRC, so your conditional wouldn't work for strings or floats either. Don't worry about how much you type, the difference is trivial. Worry about readability.

Comment: There's no way to write a variadic switch macro because there's no way to refer to individual variadic arguments. The preprocessor's facilities are *very* limited.

Comment: I still think it's more readable without the switch. There's a reason it's not in Python... So 'readable' is a personal preference here. Anyway, my confusion was in switch(3) { case X: case Y: } being legal, I've never seen that before.

Comment: @Kevin "I'd bet the compiler is smart enough to optimize those trivial conditions to switches/gotos" -- It's not wise to bet that compilers can't do what they are well known to do.

Comment: @Kevin Apparently you have seen very little C code and no C textbooks or reference manuals.

Comment: @Kevin it isn't in Python precisely because no one cared to implement it. It's precisely because you can say `if n in items:` that you don't need it. There's no criticism of switch from the Python developers other than that, in Python, it's unnecessary. See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3103/ for more

Comment: @Jim Balter Compilers are well known to optimize. Not often very well, but a non-optimizing compiler is trivial. Anyway, can you point me to anywhere that uses switch(3) { case X: case Y:} where X and Y are variables? (I thought only constants were allowed in cases.)

Comment: @Kevin You're being silly or something worse. Switch statement optimization is common in compilers and that's what you bet on. "where X and Y are variables" -- Well, it would have helped if you had said what you were talking about in the first place. Upper case identifiers in C are usually constant expressions, which can be used in case labels. But you're right, switches don't handle the general case.

Comment: @Rafe: Testing equality with `==` works just fine for strings and any other class type that properly defines the operator.  It probably wouldn't have the desired effect with *pointers* of course.  And some float values are exact and can be tested exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you also tagged your question with C, here is an answer that only works with C99 and variadic macros, C++ doesn't have that. Use [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr) to do statement unrolling

```
#define TESTIT(WHAT, X, I) X == WHAT
#define TEST_MORE(WHAT, ...) P99_FOR(WHAT, P99_NARG(__VA_ARGS__), P00_OR, TESTIT, __VA_ARGS__)
```

This here

```
TEST_MORE(A, b, c, d, e, f)
TEST_MORE(3, b, c, d, e, f)
```

becomes then

```
((((((((b == A) || (c == A))) || (d == A))) || (e == A))) || (f == A))
((((((((b == 3) || (c == 3))) || (d == 3))) || (e == 3))) || (f == 3))
```

Compared to boost this has the advantage that the final call to `TEST_MORE` is simple and readable.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely can be done using the facilities in Boost's [boost::preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) package (which can be used with C as well as C++).

Comment: The preprocessor only allows variadic macro arguments to be referenced as a group (`__VA_ARGS__`) and there's nothing that boost::preprocessor or any other package can do to change that -- if you want to iterate over the arguments, you must do it in C/C++ code.

Comment: @Jim:  I disagree.  I've posted an example that utilizes the preprocessor.  It's quite straightforward to do this sort of thing, especially when using Boost.Preprocessor to do all the hard work.

Comment: @James Yes, I retract that! While it is true for *arbitrary* variadic argument lists, boost handles up to something like 256 arguments by defining a separate macro for each number of arguments, and has macros that return true if there are n arguments and false otherwise. I'm still trying to comprehend the code, but it is quite devious (and massive).